# dialog and gauge + yesno widget

Tags: bash, dialog

I'm trying an example of combining a *yesno* widget to modify the input of a *gauge* widget. But it fails. My code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
PCT=0;i=0
(
while [[ $PCT -le 100 ]]
do
cat <<EOF
XXX
$PCT
el % es ${PCT}
XXX
EOF

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
i=$((i+1))
dialog  --yesno "Si o No?" 15 61

case $? in
  0)
    PCT=$(($PCT+20));;
  1)
    PCT=$PCT;;
  255)
    echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
done
#
#PCT=$(($PCT+10))
sleep 1
done
) |

dialog --title "GAUGE" --gauge "Este es un ejemplo de gauge" 20 70 0
```

I want it to display a `yesno` dialog, where if the user presses **`Yes`**, it adds 20 to `PCT`, otherwise `PCT` keeps its value.

Please could you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting the `yesno` widget into the pipe, you could make a few small changes to the script:

- make a temporary file, e.g.,

  `MYPIPE=$(mktemp)`
- add the `--stderr` option to the `yesno` widget (so it does not interfere with the actual data)
- change the "sleep 1" to "echo sleep" (it will be processed later)
- modify the end of the loop to write the data (which is now piped using the "|" mark) into this temporary file, and
- after your loop, execute the set of data, either sleeping when "sleep" is found, or echoing otherwise, and piping *that* to the gauge widget.

An example follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYPIPE=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $MYPIPE" EXIT ERR
PCT=0;i=0

while [[ $PCT -le 100 ]]
do
cat >>$MYPIPE <<EOF
XXX
$PCT
el % es ${PCT}
XXX
EOF

for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
i=$((i+1))
dialog  --stderr --yesno "$PCT: Si o No?" 15 61

case $? in
  0)
    PCT=$(($PCT+20));;
  255)
    echo "ESC pressed.";;
esac
done

echo sleep >>$MYPIPE
done

while :
do
read MYDATA
[ -z "$MYDATA" ] && break
[ "x$MYDATA" = "xsleep" ] && sleep 1
[ "x$MYDATA" != "xsleep" ] && echo "$MYDATA"
done <$MYPIPE | \
dialog --title "GAUGE" --gauge "Este es un ejemplo de gauge" 20 70 0
```